# Creating Excel file via PHP

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

For creating DOCX files, I'm using phpdocx's software which is working great.
But now I need to create XLSX files via PHP. The data is input via many forms and need to create corresponding Excel files with multiple sheets and graphs etc etc.
Is there any tool (including paid one) out there that can generate Excel files via PHP ?
The closest I'm come across is this - [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) but this is now forwarded to [PhpSpreadsheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet), which is not yet released.

Comment: what is wrong with phpexcel? from the link you provided you can download it and use following also a full list of examples

Comment: As the documentation you linked to says, you can still use PHPExcel, which is stable, until PHPSpreadsheet is released, or you can manually install PHPSpreadsheet already and be an early adopter. There will be breaking changes between PHPExcel and PHPSpreadsheet, but I guess it should be fairly easy to migrate unless you are going to fully exploit all the complex features of PHPExcel.